# Implement CardView As Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to place the cardview as a fragment. What I wanted from the application is, there will be few cardviews on the fragment. By clicking on any of the fragment, it will launch specific activity.

However, during the process of converting the original source code which is an activity to the one I wanted; a fragment. Errors has occurred.

One of it is,

**Error:(86, 39) error: no suitable constructor found for LinearLayoutManager(CardViewFragment)
constructor LinearLayoutManager.LinearLayoutManager(Context,int,boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor LinearLayoutManager.LinearLayoutManager(Context) is not applicable
(actual argument CardViewFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)**

This is my converted source code, the same original code was inside it too except that is has been commented out.

```
package info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;


public class CardViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CardView cardView;

    private ArrayList<FeddProperties> os_versions;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    // private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    //||Before
    /*protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initContrls();
    }*/

    private LinearLayout llLayout;
    private FragmentActivity faActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        faActivity = (FragmentActivity) super.getActivity();
        llLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        initContrls();

        return llLayout;
    }

    private void initContrls() {

        // toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //  cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        //if (toolbar != null) {
        //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Android Versions");

        //}

        final String[] versions = {"Alpha", "Beta", "CupCake", "Donut",
                "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb",
                "Ice Cream Sandwitch", "JellyBean", "KitKat", "LollyPop"};
        //final int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.donut, R.drawable.eclair, R.drawable.froyo, R.drawable.gingerbread, R.drawable.honeycomb, R.drawable.icecream_sandwhich, R.drawable.jellybean, R.drawable.kitkat, R.drawable.lollipop};


        os_versions = new ArrayList<FeddProperties>();

        for (int i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
            FeddProperties feed = new FeddProperties();

            feed.setTitle(versions[i]);
            //feed.setThumbnail(icons[i]);
            os_versions.add(feed);
        }

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // ListView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //Grid View
        // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,1,false));

        //StaggeredGridView
        // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1));

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(os_versions);

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }
}
```

Can any of you assist on this?

Comment: read the error. this constructor `new LinearLayoutManager(this)` does not exists. read the doc to find the constructor suited to your situation

Answer (score 0):

The `LinearLayoutManager` constructor is expecting a `Context` instance. The typical context used would be your activity:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```